# Error appeared when I want to add a permission to a user or join it to a group in django

Tags: django

In django admin panel... after creating a user I can't give that a permission or specify a group for that

actually after setting the intended permission or group clicking on save button will cause this error

```
syntax error at or near "ON"
LINE 1: ...ser_groups" ("user_id", "group_id") VALUES (2, 1) ON CONFLIC...
```

the data base engine:

```
'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
```

Comment: Which Database and Django db backend are you using? Can you add your DATABASES setting to your question

Comment: Postgresql, i added the engine @IainShelvington

Comment: Which version of Postgresql are you running? `ON CONFLICT` is only supported from 9.5 onwards

Comment: Mine is 9.3, I'll be thankful if you let me know the quickest way for  upgrading that without losing the data @IainShelvington

Comment: Postgres has docs regarding upgrading https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/install-upgrading.html